# Google поиск с помощью python

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать гугл поиск с помощью python. Знаю, что есть `scrapy.org` и GCS(google custom search), но как можно вводить слова и получать информацию с веб страниц? Есть какие-то идеи как начать и чем продолжить?
Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&q=google+search+api+python+module

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), простой пример есть в ответах на англоязычном стаке, например, здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598648/searching-google-with-selenium-and-python

Comment: lIyenko, а как можно создать эту кнопку для поиска, tkinter юзать?